# Where to buy ingredients and tools for brewing in UK?

Tags: shopping

I'm moving soon to UK and I would like to keep on brewing my beers there, does anyone know a shop where to get the tools (fermenters, heat exchanger, and so on) and ingreds (malts, hops yeasts and so on)

thanks,

Comment: You may want to specify the city you're moving to. There are local brick & mortar shops in many cities in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.hopandgrape.co.uk/public/catalog.asp

and

http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Home_brew_Starter_Kits.html

are both in the UK.

Brouwland offers shipping to the UK:

http://www.brouwland.com/en/?gclid=CMuR77T4wLwCFSuQcgodjQcALg

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of [The Malt Miller](http://www.themaltmiller.co.uk/) for my ingredients.  Best and most consistent service I've had, and he crushes your grains to order so they're as fresh as possible.

I also got my mash tun and boiler from him (not the ones he currently stocks), and I've been very happy with them.

Answer (score 2):

[UK Highstreet Shop](http://www.wilko.com/kitchen/homebrew/icat/homebrewing) (If you want to kill your local homebrew shops)
[My Local Shop](http://www.easyhomebrew.co.uk)
[My Goto UK Online Shop](http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/) (<-- I think everyone agrees)
[Cheapest UK Cam Locks](http://www.angelhomebrew.co.uk/en/12-camlock-fittings) (for DIY)
[Cheapest & Best UK Tap Kit](http://www.angelhomebrew.co.uk/en/taps-and-fittings/17-2-piece-12-weldless-tap-kit.html) (for DIY, all SS)
[Cheapest & Safe Food grade water pump](http://shop.solarproject.co.uk/sp2020-easy-connect-water-circulation-pump-%C3%82%C2%A3260-p-10.html) (for DIY)